# Is there a word to describe "Water seeps through paper cup"

Tags: single-word-requests

As per title, is there a single regular word for that?

For instance, you are in a restaurant with a cup of coffee served in a paper cup *(let's pretend this restaurant serves coffee in paper cup)*. After some time, you noticed the coffee stain on the bottom of the cup and the coffee seeps through. You want to approach the waiter to change the paper cup. Other than telling the waiter *"the coffee seeps through the paper cup"*, is there a single regular word to describe that?

Thanks

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used (as per the tag details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cup **leaks**.

Yes, it leaks slowly, but it still leaks, in that liquid is getting through.

> [American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/leak): To permit the escape, entry, or passage of something through a breach or flaw.

Or

This cup has a **leak**.